# What is the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Data Nuget Package for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I understand that the minimum Nuget packages that I need for an ASP.NET MVC 4 Project are:

- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4
- Microsoft ASP.NET Razor 2
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

However I am interested to know, what would the following packages add to the project?

- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Data
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Web Data

i.e. What do these two packages do? The description for each of these nuget projects is the same description as Razor 2 package, which isn't too helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After doing some experimenting with MVC 4 Projects with and without the following packages

- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Data
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Web Data

I have come to the conclusion that the Nuget Package description of

> This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages.
>   ASP.NET Web Pages and the new Razor syntax provide a fast, terse,
>   clean and lightweight way to combine server code with HTML to create
>   dynamic web content.

is very misleading.

The Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Data actually just contains the WebMatrix.Data.dll. This the only assembly that is added to your project when adding this package.
Looking at the [MSDN reference for this assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548073%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

> The WebMatrix.Data namespace contains classes that simplify database
>   interaction in ASP.NET Web Pages. This namespace includes classes that
>   help you to open, query, and send commands to a database, and to work
>   with database rows that are returned by SQL queries.

And for the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Web Data, this package only adds the WebMatrix.DataWeb.dll (dependent on WebMatrix.Data.dll).
The [MSDN reference for this assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is

> The WebMatrix.WebData namespace contains classes that simplify
>   membership and security in ASP.NET Web Pages. This namespace includes
>   classes that help you create and delete user accounts, define roles,
>   and manage account passwords.

So if not using WebMatrix Data to access databases and not using the simple membership provider, these packages are unnecessary.

If you are using the Simple Membership provider, or extending the Extended Membership Provider, then these packages are necessary.

Comment: I don't think they're misleading, although they are maybe not complete.  These packages are for Web Pages projects, but MVC uses them as well.  In addition, you may also need several other packages to take full advantage, such as the OAuth/OpenID packages.

Comment: Fair enough @MystereMan. I think that if I had a better understanding of the whole Web Matrix and Web Pages libraries, I would agree. Coming from purely MVC I don't yet have that understanding, but trying to get there :-)

Comment: I would agree with Sylvia J. Another point is why have they been added to the standard MVC Internet App project? What is their purpose with regards to MVC? Is there something MVC doesn't have that these libraries do have? Or is it just adding unnecessary confusion?

Comment: +1.  I think the description is misleading as you don't need WebMatrix to use Razor.